# How to pass value from form checkboxes with ajax to mail

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need help with value sending to mail from form on html page, 
there is 3 file: test.html with form group checkbox, contact.php and contact.js

This is the contact.js:

```
$(function () {

$('#contact-form').validator();

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

and this is contact.php for processing form to mail

```
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message' 'checkboxes' => 'Colors');
```

form group is:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Colors:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="form_checkboxes1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="form_checkboxes1" value="Blue"> + Blue
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="form_checkboxes2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="form_checkboxes2" value="Green"> + Green
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="form_checkboxes3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="form_checkboxes3" value="Orange"> + Orange
    </label>
</div>
```

the problem is when choose an option for Colors or choose every three colors after mail sent result is Colors: array

now, I trie to change line in contact.php  adding

```
$checkboxes = implode(',',$_POST['checkboxes']);
```

but no succsess

rest of kod in contact.php is:

```
try{
    $emailText = "text";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";}
        }
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
```

Comment: So either process the the array as an array because you asked the browser to pass you an array by using `name="checkboxes[]"` or change the HTML and give each checkbox its own name i.e. `name="red"` `name="orange"` `name="green"`

Comment: I changed all name to suggested red, orange and green on html and nothing happen, this code from Nikhil Vaghla works excellent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it's works for you.
your code not working because of you have pass array in color so you need to implode your array and then paas to you mail.
i have try this and it's works fine.

```
try{
    $emailText = "text";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
           $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: " . implode(',', $value) . "\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";}
        }
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
```